# d3 line chart, dates on the left and values top

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts

I'm wanting to change http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569 so the date axle is moved to the left, and values moved to the top, like:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ibHxOki.png]

I do not want to rotate the SVG to accomplish this.

I've tried playing with the Y and X axis's but no luck.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse,
    bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left,
    formatValue = d3.format(",.2f"),
    formatCurrency = function(d) { return "$" + formatValue(d); };

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); })
    .interpolate('cardinal');

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.date - b.date;
  });

  x.domain([data[0].date, data[data.length - 1].date]);
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

  var focus = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "focus")
      .style("display", "none");

  focus.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

  focus.append("text")
      .attr("x", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic things that you need to do is switch the x and y scales, axes, and make some positioning and orientation changes.

- change the x scale to linear
- change the y scale to time
- change the x scale's orientation to "top"
- remove the translation of the x axis so it stays at the top
- swap the values returned by the x and y accessors in the line generator
- swap the domains of the x and y scales

With those changes, you end up with something like this: http://bl.ocks.org/trinary/b1a5f453c51231cd7bb5

You can change how the y axis behaves by inverting its range.